# How can I get PostSharp to emit a message to the build window in VisualStudio for my Aspect

Tags: postsharp

I have an aspect (attribute) that I want to be sure is being added to the correct classes/events during compile time (technically, after compile time when PostSharp is instrumenting the code), so I have tried to add a WriteLine statement in the CompileTimeInitialize() method, but nothing is ever emitted to the "build" window:

```
[PSerializable]
public class LogEventAttribute : EventInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(EventInfo targetEvent, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine($">>>> EVENT: {targetEvent.Name} CLASS: {targetEvent.DeclaringType?.FullName}");
        base.CompileTimeInitialize(targetEvent, aspectInfo);
    }
}
```

I have also tried `Console.Error.WriteLine()`, `Debug.WriteLine()`, and `Trace.WriteLine()` all to no avail. Any suggestions as there appears to be no documentation (that I can find anyway) regarding this on the PostSharp site.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Message.Write](https://doc.postsharp.net/overload_postsharp_extensibility_message_write).

Console.WriteLine does not work because compilation happens in a background process.